# Функции реализованные в git

Tags: git

Часто приходится добавлять файлы в git репозитории, а потом что бы из запушить нужно сделать следующие команды:

```
git add super.file
git commit -m "add super.file"
git push origin develop
```

Вот и возник вопрос существует ли в git функция для автоматического ввода этих команд или может кто знает как автоматизировать их, что бы можно было пушить с нужным комментарием одной командой?

Comment: Просто напишите нужный вам скрипт или алиас для вашего интерпретатора команд, наверное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы можете использовать команду `git commit -am 'commit name'` - это команда добавит все файлы и сделает коммит. Но команду для пуша придется писать в ручную.
2. Создайте алиас например: `git pushdev --global alias.co git add .; git commit -m 'commit name'; git push origin develop`. Разделить команд вы можете заменить на `||` если используете баш.
3. Создайте баш скрипт читаь можно тут https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/325522/